# How do you allow user_t SELinux users the ability to use sudo

Tags: sudo, selinux

I've got three classes of user that I have assigned to `staff_t`, `user_t` and `guest_t`. However the default permissions of these user types don't exactly correspond to what I need. It seemed easier to use the existing three definitions rather than attempt to define a completely new types. In particular, the users that are assigned as `user_t` need to be able to run `sudo` - not to run commands as root but only to run predefined commands as other users, also assigned as `user_t`. I don't mind if this first entails using `newrole` to adopt a supplementary role other than `user_t` provided that doesn't involve typing passwords.

I haven't been able to find clear details on how to do this. So I've had to try to make sense of how it is configured for, e.g `staff_t`. I can guess at some of the transitions that are needed but I suspect that there's actually an m4 macro or two which will do the job. There's an `sudodomain` attribute which is applied to `staff_sudo_t`. Interestingly, `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/users/user_u` contains a line for `user_sudo_t` but the `user_sudo_t` type doesn't exist. But this reinforces my perception that this might be a common thing to configure so shouldn't be as difficult as I'm finding.

I'm using a RHEL 9 system with FreeIPA.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://blog.siphos.be/2010/09/selinux-quicky/) already? It looks like you need a rule, a transition and an entry point.